# Vertical Align & Navigation Problems

Tags: html, css

Site: http://tripleo.biz/test/index.html
Please shrink browser to mobile view.

Header:
I have problems with the alignment. They don't seem to align all to the middle of the header. The Android logo seems ot be the only thing aligned. The text and dash image aren't. :/

Navigation:
The Navigation Drop Down is in effect when you mouse-over "ALL" but the links after Link 2 are hidden behind the image. I tried to use z-index to fix this issue but nothing still.

Content Area:
Another problem with Vertical align. For some reason there is more space at the bottom of the content.

**Index.html**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styled.css">

    <!--[if IE]> <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <header>    
            <div class="image_carousel">
            <img src="images/menu.png" style="width: 15px; height: 22px;" />
            <img src="images/android_icon.png" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 26px; height: 46px;" />
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="#" id="menu-icon">ALL</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">LINK1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK5</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </header>

    <section>
        <img src="images/headerimg.jpg" />

        <div class="bround">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" class="imgleft" width="75px" />
        <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat quam vitae mauris lacinia, id tincidunt eros lobortis.</b> 
        <p class="bauthor">Olajide Olaolorun | <a href="">1 Comment</a></p>
           </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="bround">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" class="imgleft" />
        <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat quam vitae mauris lacinia, id tincidunt eros lobortis.</b>
        <p class="bauthor">Olajide Olaolorun | <a href="">1 Comment</a></p>
           </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>


    </section>

    <footer>

        <p>Copyright Confidential</p>

    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
img {

    width: 100%;

}

header {

    background: #83aa01;
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    vertical-align:middle;

}

.image_carousel {
    padding: 5px 0 1px 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
}

.image_carousel img {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    bottom:0px;
}

.clearfix {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}

div.bround {
background-color: #FFF;
color: #000;
padding: 20px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 0px;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;

}

img.imgleft {
    position:relative; 
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px; 
    width: 60px;
}

.bauthor {
color: #D3D3D3;
}

.bauthor a {
color: #83aa01;
}



#menu-icon {

    display: hidden;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

div.nav {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    bottom:0px;
    color: #FFF;


}


    div.nav ul, div.nav:active ul { 

        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0px;
        background: #444;
        color: #FFF;
        top: 50px;
        width: 20%;
        border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;

    }

    div.nav li {

        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px 0;
        margin: 0px;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFF;
        z-index:1000;
    }

    div.nav:hover ul {

        display: block;

    }

div.nav ul, div.nav a { 

        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: normal;
        letter-spacing:2px;

}


ul {

    list-style: none;

}

li {

    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px

}
```

-
Please Help!

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like three separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Header :**
set your **.image_carousel** padding-top value to 15px and remove **margin-top** from your android icon. which looks like this

```
.image_carousel {
padding: 15px 0 1px 1px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: left;
}
```

**Content  Area :**
You have Given `margin-bottom :20px` to your **p** tag Just remove that .

Comment: Thanks. But when the browser is in full size not on mobile, the icon image is still bigger than the rounded box.

Comment: Fixed it with min-height.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Navigation issue, You need to add z-index for the dropdown menu. Update your css like below it will resolve.

```
div.nav ul, div.nav a
{
color:#fff;
font-size:17px;
font-weight:normal;
letter-spacing:2px;
z-index:10;
}
```

Regarding the Content Area padding is coming from the following class

```
section
{
 margin:80px auto 40px;
 max-width:980px;
 position:relative;
 padding:20px;
}
```

If you remove the margin bottom 40px, it will work fine in mobile. But the problem is you wont get enough space on bigger screens. So you can use media query and apply this class only on mobile versions.

```
 @media all and (max-width: 399px)
{
  section
  {
    margin-bottom:0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your content area solution is wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Test css copy code

```
header {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #83AA01;
height: 76px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;
}
.image_carousel {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.image_carousel img, .image_carousel > .nav {
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
display: inline-block;
height: 74px;
line-height: 74px;
padding: 0 30px;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
}
 .image_carousel > .nav:hover {
   background-color: #FF0000;
}
.image_carousel > .nav ul li {
   line-height: normal;
 }
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
 }
div.bround {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   border-radius: 15px;
   color: #000000;
   margin-right: 0;
   padding: 20px;
}
img.imgleft {
   float: left;
   margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
   position: relative;
   width: 60px;
}
.bauthor {
  color: #D3D3D3;
}
.bauthor a {
  color: #83AA01;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
   font-size: 20px;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
  }
   div.nav ul, div.nav:active ul {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #444444;
  border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   display: none;
  left: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top:30px;
}
 div.nav li {
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 5px 0;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
 div.nav li:hover{
    background-color:red;
 }
 div.nav:hover ul {
     display: block;
     top: 43px;
 }
 div.nav ul, div.nav a {
     color: #FFFFFF;
     font-size: 17px;
     font-weight: normal;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
}
ul {
     list-style: none outside none;
 }
li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
 }

 //yes test html 

 <header>    
        <div class="image_carousel">
        <img src="images/menu.png" />
        <img src="images/android_icon.png" />
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon">ALL</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">LINK1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK5</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</header>

<section>
    <img src="images/headerimg.jpg" />

    <div class="bround">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" class="imgleft" width="75px" />
    <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat quam vitae mauris lacinia, id tincidunt eros lobortis.</b> 
    <p class="bauthor">Olajide Olaolorun | <a href="">1 Comment</a></p>
       </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="bround">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" class="imgleft" />
    <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat quam vitae mauris lacinia, id tincidunt eros lobortis.</b>
    <p class="bauthor">Olajide Olaolorun | <a href="">1 Comment</a></p>
       </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>


</section>

<footer>

    <p>Copyright Confidential</p>

</footer>
```